# Unable to close modal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm writing some js code in my ebook project. The problem is in a modal, used to show, like a popup, reference from others pages.
Here is the part of my project dedicated to close the modal.

```
    // Riferimento al Modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modalversetti');
// Riferimento allo <span> che chiude il Modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// Quando l'utente preme sullo <span> (x), si chiude il Modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

And here (better) all the code (js+html+css) showing the modal running but unable to close.
https://jsfiddle.net/emanuele_tinari/gkL5sh3x/
Modal built via js run very well, but, unfortunately, close button seems don't.
thanks.

Comment: First place you should be looking is in your developer console. `span is undefined`. This is the very first step in debugging your application.

Comment: have you checked the`close button is availible in the dom before adding the click function? it's build in dynamicly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to find the `close` span to attach the listener immediately when the page loads. You haven't created the modal at this point, so it fails.

If you cut the chunk of code in your question and paste it immediately at the end of the function that creates your modal, the close button will work.

Comment: Now it's ok. Modal open and close as I want. Unfortunately another problem seems to be: if I click 2, 3 or more times the link opening the modal, in the modal i find text repeated 2, 3 or more times (depends how many times i click the link).
Here the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/emanuele_tinari/gkL5sh3x/

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work :

```
  document.onclick = function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    if (el.className == "close") {
    // Riferimento al Modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('modalversetti');

        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

but you have more problems with your code ...

Comment: What do you mean with, cit: "you have more problems with your code ... " ?

Comment: Can you suggest me what, about you, are the problems and how to solvers ? There are some improvements to apply, it about you? In effect close modal in my ebook seems not go. in JSfiddle or on Tryit Editor on w3schools.com go. I don't understand...